# Why doesn't Rails update its association cache when creating new records through the association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses, -> { order("created_at DESC") }
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'should return the last address the user created' do
    user = User.create!
    user.addresses.create!(created_at: Date.today - 1.day)
    user.addresses.create!(created_at: Date.today)
    assert_equal Date.today, user.addresses.first.created_at # note that .first here should actually return the last record created, when hitting the DB, due to the ordering specified in the association scope block
  end
end
```

This assertion would fail (`user.addresses.first.created_at` returns `Date.today-1.day`), while if I did `user.reload` or `user.addresses.reset` right before the assertion, it would succeed (`user.addresses.first.created_at` then returns `Date.today`).

Why doesn't Rails update its association cache when creating new records through the association?

I would have expected using `user.addresses.create` would actually have updated the cached association on the user object, as well as the DB record, since it is created through the association. As opposed to using `Address.create`, in which case I would expect the need to reload the user object.

Answer (score 0):

I assume because it would be too expensive and unnecessary in most situations. I usually write these specs as:

```
assert_equal Date.today, user.addresses.reload.first.created_at
```